# FullCalendar 5.0.0-beta.4 ThirdPartyDraggable - How to delay click?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, sortablejs, fullcalendar-5

I'm trying to use SortableJS with ThirdPartyDraggable. On touch devices I have a 500ms delay before the click is allowed, but the 3rd party draggable registers the click right away.

Is there some way to notify the ThirdPartyDraggable manually to start listening to the click?